# writing datafram to local path encountered error

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

Code works perfectly on my laptop, but encountered error while running on desktop

```
    resultRDD.toDF().show()
    resultRDD.toDF().write.format("delta").save(outputPath)
```

The results can be shown, but the write operation encountered below:

```
21/05/25 17:26:48 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
ExitCodeException exitCode=-1073741515: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:585)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:482)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:776)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:869)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:852)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:733)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:225)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:209)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:328)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:398)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:461)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:440)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:911)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:892)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.HadoopOutputFile.create(HadoopOutputFile.java:74)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.<init>(ParquetFileWriter.java:248)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:390)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:349)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.<init>(ParquetOutputWriter.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(ParquetFileFormat.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.newOutputWriter(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.<init>(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$15(FileFormatWriter.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:444)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:447)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
21/05/25 17:26:48 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2)
ExitCodeException exitCode=-1073741515: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:585)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:482)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:776)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:869)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:852)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:733)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:225)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:209)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:328)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:398)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:461)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:440)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:911)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:892)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.HadoopOutputFile.create(HadoopOutputFile.java:74)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.<init>(ParquetFileWriter.java:248)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:390)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:349)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.<init>(ParquetOutputWriter.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(ParquetFileFormat.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.newOutputWriter(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.<init>(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$15(FileFormatWriter.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:444)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:447)
```

The maven pom.xml is:

```
<artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.delta</groupId>
            <artifactId>delta-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-yarn_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.alibaba/druid -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>druid</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

and i tried putting winutil.exe and hadoop.dll into %HADOOP_HOME%/bin and windows/system32 which did not work

and i have sparkhome and hadoop home set up properly

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with the answer from: https://github.com/jleetutorial/scala-spark-tutorial/issues/2   gotta install both x86 and x64 vcredist 2010 to fix it